# Excel VBA fill textbox with autocomplete in IE11

Tags: javascript, vba, excel, internet-explorer-11

How can I fill a textbox that uses javascript to suggest available entries using Excel VBA? Filling the textbox manually, I would start typing a few letters and a list of available inputs I could choose from will appear below the textbox. I need to click with my mouse or use the arrow keys to navigate to the entry I want in the javascript dropdown box and click enter.

This is the key difference with other regular input boxes. If I simply enter the text in the input box and proceed to the next input box without choosing the entry from the dropdown box, the input does not register.  So I cannot simply find the element of the input box and change its value.  I believe I need to execute the javascript that activates the dropdown box which I must then select from it.

The HTML code for the input textbox is:

```
<td id="input2" class="createInputField" colspan="0" valign="middle"
  <input value="" id="" name="docTypeDisplay" title="Document Type" size="18" type="text">
  <input value="" name="docType" type="hidden">
  <input value="" name="docTypeID" type="hidden">
```

There are 5 event listeners on the first input tag line of the code above - blur, dblclick, focus, keydown and keypress from a javascript.  I tried looking up the javascript but it is not readily understandable and is H-U-G-E!  So with this limitation in mind, here's what I've tried:

```
IE.Document.getElementById("input2").getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Value = "Monthly Report"
Set objEvent = IE.Document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
objEvent.initEvent "change", False, True
IE.Document.getElementById("input2").getElementsByTagName("input")(0).dispatchEvent objEvent
```

and variations by changing the first argument in objEvent.initEvent to "blur", "dblclick", "focus", "keydown" and "keypress". I don't get any errors and the input does not register.

Then I've tried:

```
IE.Document.getElementById("input2").getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Value = "Monthly Report"       
IE.Document.getElementById("input2").getElementsByTagName("input")(0).FireEvent ("onchange")
```

and also tried:

```
IE.Document.getElementById("input2").getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Focus  
IE.Document.getElementById("input2").getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Value = "Monthly Report"
IE.Document.getElementById("input2").getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Blur
```

and nothing has worked.

Can anyone help please?  I think I've exhausted google looking for a solution for this.

Comment: I guess there is not an URL to share? Have you tried combining events? Sometimes you need a particular order the mimics your keyboard actions. I sometimes find SendKeys down and tab can be useful tricks to try.

Comment: @QHarr, you are correct, sorry no URL to share.  I have tried calling the javascript events in different order and combinations but nothing has worked.  It's a needle in a haystack as I'm not even sure what each event is supposed to do.  I will say I have been able to activate a dropdown input box in the form with:                                                                                    
 Set objEvent = IE.Document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
 objEvent.initEvent "change", False, True
 IE.Document.getElementById("DropdownInput").dispatchEvent objEvent

Answer (score 0):

Using sendkeys, I was able to fill the input box, wait for the suggested input to show up in the dropdown box and then simulate an "Enter" keypress to register the input.  I found Application.SendKeys "Enter" didn't work and so I had to improvise.  I suspect the "Enter" key may be tied to the Keypress javascript event.

```
IE.Document.getElementById("input2").getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Focus
Application.SendKeys "Monthly Report"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))   'Wait for javascript to fire and suggest an input
Application.SendKeys "~"    'This simulates an "Enter" keypress on the first suggested input
```

This script will fail though if at anytime during the Excel VBA execution I click on another window.  I am hoping someone will come along with a more reliable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Y-E-S! I finally found something that worked through trial and error without using SendKeys.  Credit to @QHarr to suggest trying combining events, which kept me going in the right direction.  So this is what worked for me:

```
'First fill the input box with text
IE.Document.getElementById("input2").getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Value = "Monthly Report"

'Fire the keypress event to start the javascript to suggest an input
Set objEvent = IE.Document.createEvent("keyboardEvent")
objEvent.initEvent "keypress", True, False
IE.Document.getElementById("input2").getElementsByTagName("input")(0).dispatchEvent objEvent

'Wait for a few seconds for the javascript to complete creating the dropdown box
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

'Select the first suggested input from the dropdown box. I noticed a new element was created when the dropdown box appeared, which I simulated a click on.
IE.Document.getElementById("suggest_input2").getElementsByClassName("object")(0).Click
```

Only one more thing I would like to change with this answer before it's perfect, which is to replace the application.wait time with a more robust line.  Trying the code below didn't work.  Any ideas how I can tell Excel VBA to wait for a javascript to finish loading before proceeding?

```
While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
```